# How to launch a Google Chrome Tab with specific URL from Internet Explorer 11 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

My application is coded in C# (ASP.NET 4.7.2 Full).

On my client the default browser is `Internet Explorer 11`

I open the example webpage on `Internet Explorer 11`

On this example webpage I have

```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server"
       OnClick="btn_Click"
       ImageUrl="/img/icon.gif" />


    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int pk = Convert.ToInt32(gvProducts.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);

        string queryString = "Default3.aspx?sID=" + pk.ToString();

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = queryString.ToString() + " --new-window";
        process.Start();
    }
```

I need open the `Default3.aspx` page with browser Chrome in new window.

But my code don't working because the `Default3.aspx` doesn't open.

Is there a way I can launch a tab (new Window) in Google Chrome with a specific URL loaded into it from a browser Internet Explorer?

Thanks for help.

Comment: This might work working locally. But if you deploy the App e.g. on a VM the Browser will open in the VM. Please check TaskManager, Chrome might be open, but not for your account

Comment: @MarkusMeyer thanks I don't have to distribute the application. It's just a tutorial for a university assignment

Comment: Then you have to ensure that the process running the App uses the same account like you are using

Comment: @MarkusMeyer okay

Comment: That btn_Click runs on the server side, so it tries to start Chrome on *the server*. Which may be the same as your client, in a development environment.

Comment: A web application cannot tell another application on the client machine to start. a) It doesn't have permissions (imagine the fun a hacker could have with that), and b) there's no guarantee it would work anyway, since you can't guarantee what O/S the client will have or what apps will be installed. Let's take a step back and ask _why_ you need this? have you implemented something in your page which isn't supported by Internet Explorer? If so then, you can either 1) change your code to be supported by IE, or 2) recommended to users that they only run your site in Chrome (or Edge) to begin with.

Comment: @ADyson I have implemented saving clipboard images to file in C# using canvas on my app but this working only in Google Chrome browser. This is the problem.

Comment: Ok. Well I've already told you what your options are. The thing you are asking for is impossible so you have to think about the alternatives. P.s. It's likely it would work in Edge and Firefox too (but you should test to be sure), so Chrome is probably not the only option that people could choose. Just make it clear that I.e. is not supported

Comment: Another option too is to detect IE and then use fallback functionality - i.e. standard file uploads instead of canvas, so the user would have to paste the clipboard contents into another app such as Paint, save it to the disk, and then upload it. So it's more work for them but at least there could be some usage of the app in IE rather than none

Comment: @ADyson thanks resolved using browser Microsoft EDGE!

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You can post your solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou I just changed the browser and went from IE 11 to Edge. Using Edge and Chrome the save clipboard images to file in C# using canvas working correctly